# T and T*T are simultaneously diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I suspect the following might be true but I can't prove it.

Suppose $T \in \text{End}(V)$ for some finite-dimensional complex inner product space $V$, such that $T^*T = TT^*$ (i.e. $T$ is normal). Prove that if

$$T^*T = UDU^*$$

for some unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$ then the columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of T.

Equivalently, prove that $U^*TU$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not work if $T$ has multiple eigenvalues of the same modulus.

For example, let
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $T^*=-T$, $TT^*=T^*T=I$ so we can pick $U=I$.  But $T$ is not diagonal.

Comment: Does this imply that the first paragraph on page 199 (page 3 of the pdf) of the following link is incorrect? or am I understanding something? https://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter6.pdf

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect.  On the eigenspace of $A^*A$ we need to do a separate argument for the diagonalisation of $A$.  Or you can do it in one go with unitary upper-triangularisation of $A$.